# Nodejs - httpsRequest reporting back as undefined at certain times when response is not 200

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below JS function to query httpsRequest, sometimes it goes thru fine with 200 response when going thru 100s of urls, certain times it fails with undefined response.

```
 assert.js:86
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  AssertionError: 200 == undefined
at C:\Users\test\Desktop\node_modules\workers-STAGE.js:73:11
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\test\Desktop\node_modules\workers-S
   TAGE.js:54:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:271:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:129:20)
at net.js:459:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

My Function is as below

```
function _httpsRequest(path, callback) {
var options = {
    hostname: domain,
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: "GET",
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var dataStr = "";

    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        dataStr += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function() {
        return callback(null, res.statusCode, dataStr);
    });
});
req.on("error", function(e) {
    return callback(e);
});
req.end();
```

My Question, is there a way i can handle timeouts or if the response takes longer than expected, so that it doesn't abruptly stop when testing 100's of urls.

Comment: You're saying the ``res.statusCode`` evaluates to ``undefined``?

Comment: yes `res.statusCode` evaluated to undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the issue, but perhaps this will ensure that you don't `callback()` multiple times in case that's what's happening:

```
function _httpsRequest(path, callback) {
    var options = {
        hostname: domain,
        port: 443,
        path: path,
        method: "GET",
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var dataStr = "";

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            dataStr += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", function() {
            if (responded)
                return;
            responded = true;
            return callback(null, res.statusCode, dataStr);
        });
    });
    var responded = false;

    req.on("error", function(e) {
        if (responded)
            return;
        responded = true;
        return callback(e);
    });

    req.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs mainly when concurrency is an issue, try enabling `keepAlive` in your request options.

```
var options = {
    hostname: domain,
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: "GET",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    keepAlive: true
};
```